# Python>Pandas>Summing columns in different data frames which have same column names, same index values but not same same length of index

Tags: python, pandas

i have two data frames which look like below. i want to sum df2 and df1 and override df1 to reflect this sum. though column name matches in both data frames, and even index have similar values, but DF2 is smaller in size and not have all rows(or index values). how can i best do this operation? "Buckets" is the index on both the data frame.

[image]

Comment: Try joining the 2 dataframes, df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Buckets', how='left') as df1 has more rows(or try Outer join as per your data), then sum the 2 EUR columns(may be EUR_x+EUR_y) into a diff column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to merge, let's use pandas intrinsic data aligment with indexes:

```
df1.set_index("Buckets")\
   .add(df2.set_index("Buckets"), fill_value=0)\
   .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Buckets    EUR
0     20Y  200.0
1     25Y  200.0
2     30Y  200.0
3     35Y  200.0
```

Note: You can leave out the `set_index` if Buckets is already in the index.
Do, `df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the join type left or outer, you can decide as per your data)

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Buckets'], how='left').set_index(['Buckets']).sum(axis=1).reset_index()
 #  .set_index(['Buckets'])  this is optional for you, as it is already index(as mentioned by you)
 # output,  You may have to rename column  0 to EUR after that
  Buckets      0
0     20Y  200.0
1     25Y  200.0
2     30Y  200.0
3     35Y  200.0
```

## OR try this

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Buckets'], how='left')
# you wll have 2 columns for EUR(as both df1 and df2 has it) suffixed as _x and _y
df1['EUR_y'] = df1['EUR_y'].fillna(0)  # as NaN will create issue
df1['EUR'] = df1['EUR_x'] +df1['EUR_y']
# o/p
>>> df1
  Buckets  EUR_x  EUR_y    EUR
0     20Y    100  100.0  200.0
1     25Y    200    0.0  200.0
2     30Y    200    0.0  200.0
3     35Y    400 -200.0  200.0
```